# asp.net virtual directory in php website

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

I have created an asp.net virtual directory in php website.

Used IIS to host php website.

But when I try to access the virtual directory, I get 404.

Following is the folder structure

```
--wwwroot

       --php website files

       --asp.net web application
```

Set ASP.Net extention to 4.0 (Integrated Pipeline).

Give read and write permission to the virtual directory.

Not sure what causes 404.

Comment: It should be web application, not just virtual directory.